Mac to Raspberry Pi: Intermittent Broken Pipes
When SSH'ing into my Raspbery Pi, I'll be typing away when suddenly the prompt will freeze. Then after 20 seconds or so, I get a client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe error. The time before I get disconnected also seems to vary. Sometimes it doesn't happen for a long time, other times I get it after 10 seconds.
Now I think it's not an issue with the Pi (only think though!) as I can immediately start a new connection & all things like top running on the Pi saying it's not being put under any pressure.
I've tried a few things in my .ssh/config file like setting TCPKeepAlive to no.
How can I debug and solve this issue?

What‘s in the logs, on both sides? Do you connect via LAN or WiFi?

Also, if you think it‘s not the Pi causing this, why should it be the Mac?

Broken pipe points to a network connectivity issue such as a spotty wifi connection.
"How can I debug and solve this issue?" By troubleshooting the network, not the software. As a first step, you can try switching to a hard-wired connection on both ends, or moving both devices next to your wifi router to see if the problem goes away. If that solves the problem, you can work step by step until the problem returns, e.g. by switching one device to wifi, then moving that device back to it's original location, then moving on to the other device.
If you can't find or fix the network issue, it will help somewhat to use the screen command-line tool within the SSH session so that you can reconnect to your previous terminal session after a disconnection. Or you could use Mosh instead of SSH which has resiliency against spotty connections.

The OP asks „How can I debug and solve this issue?“, not sure it helps to basically repeat this in the first paragraph of the answer. Using tmux/screen and mosh for sure would reduce the risk of loosing data etc. though.

Thanks for the feedback. Their question suggests they were trying to troubleshoot their software. My wording could be improved, but basically I was trying to explain that they should troubleshoot the network, not the software. I also gave something to try that would verify whether it's the network. I don't think it makes sense to go into more detail on troubleshooting the network at this stage without follow-up from OP.

Thanks @georgeflug. This is over an ethernet connection so the connection should be reasonably solid but there are two switches between the Mac & the PI. So I guess it's time to start isolating network components. Fun ;)
